# List local container images in AKS nodes

Tags: docker, azure-aks, containerd

I was able to get into an [Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/intro-kubernetes) (AKS) node by referring to *[Connect to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster nodes for maintenance or troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-access)*.

I am trying to list the images present in the worker node. Do I need to install anything like nerdctl/crictl in the nodes or is there any other command I can use which is readily available in the nodes?

In short, what's the alternative for Docker commands in AKS worker nodes?

containerd://1.4.9+azure is the CONTAINER-RUNTIME

Comment: This is used as an example in [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417004/message-suggested-edits-review-queue-has-been-suspended?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: The meta question has now been (automatically) deleted - now only visible with more than 10,000 reputation points.

Answer (score 1):

Check *[Why and how to use containerd from the command line](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/containerd-command-line-clients/)*. I am not sure if it helps or not. But it does have *containerd* commands to check.

The reference is *[Debugging Kubernetes nodes with crictl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/)*.

Use these commands to check:

```
sudo crictl --help
sudo crictl ps
sudo crictl images
```

Comment: thanks, but it did not help as even ctr  command is not installed in aks worker nodes.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using it inside the container. Go to the host process with `chroot /host` and use it.

The image is `--image=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0`. I used this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ctr cli tool which come prepackaged with containerd.

`ctr -n <namespace> image list`

NOTE: for checking the namespace kindly run

`ctr ns list`